Conda Not Using Expected, Base python.exe
I ruined something in Conda that now has disabled my anaconda prompt.  I believe some change occurred when I attempted to add an interpreter to Pycharm.  Unsure what I did wrong, but now when I open an Anaconda Prompt (Windows Start --> Anaconda 64 bit --> Anaconda Prompt (anaconda3)) the CL prompt opens, but the normal Base environment is not activated.  Attempting to activate it or another environment yields the below error.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\<USERNAME>\anaconda3\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\<USERNAME>\\anaconda3\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\<USERNAME>\\anaconda3\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\<USERNAME>\\anaconda3\\python39.zip',
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8\\lib',
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.8',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\

I use a program called ArcGIS, and at one point a million years ago I had to edit some Python or Conda Configuration-like file to include a path to enable license permission to a  closed-source module.  I have since forgotten that protocol, but perhaps that is the reason for the Conda's attempt to use it's executable(?) which is being populated as a sys.path.
I'm lost, would highly appreciate any ideas.
